# Why is adding an item to the empty inventory not working when done inside a loop over the inventory list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently taking an intro to scripting class and we are working on a text-based adventure game. In the game, we are supposed to move between rooms and collect items which are then added to our inventory. I have the moving directions working but I cannot seem to get the items to add to the inventory.

Here is the code:

```
def show_instructions():
    # print a main menu and the commands
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print("                         The Dwarve and The Lonely Mountain")
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print("             Collect 6 items to win the game, or get desolated by Smaug.")
    print("                     Move commands: North, East, South, West")
    print("                        Add to Inventory: Take 'item name'")
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')


show_instructions()

room = {
    'The Lonely Mountain - Secret Tunnel Entrance': {'go North': 'The Old Market'},
    'The Old Market': {'go South': 'The Lonely Mountain - Secret Tunnel Entrance', 'go West': 'The Enchantment Room',
                       'item': 'Dwarven Shield'},
    'The Enchantment Room': {'go West': 'The Library', 'go East': 'The Old Market', 'item': 'Healing Potion'},
    'The Library': {'go North': 'The Dragon Shrine', 'go East': 'The Enchantment Room', 'item': 'Dragon History Guide'},
    'The Dragon Shrine': {'go East': 'The Blacksmiths Forge', 'go South': 'The Library', 'item': 'Fire Potion'},
    'The Blacksmiths Forge': {'go North': 'The Mine', 'go West': 'The Dragon Shrine',
                              'go East': 'The Old Living Quarters',
                              'go South': 'The Treasure Room', 'item': 'Dwarven Armor'},
    'The Mine': {'go South': 'The Blacksmiths Forge', 'item': 'Dragon Axe'},
    'The Old Living Quarters': {'go West': 'The Blacksmiths Forge', 'go South': 'The Old Market',
                                'item': 'Dwarven Helm'},
    'The Treasure Room': {'go North': 'The Blacksmiths Forge', 'item': 'No item here, only a dragon to fell.'}
}

current_room = 'The Lonely Mountain - Secret Tunnel Entrance'


def get_new_current_room(current_room, direction):
    new_current_room = current_room
    for i in room:
        if i == current_room:
            if direction in room[i]:
                new_current_room = room[i][direction]
    return new_current_room


def get_item(current_room):
    if 'item' not in room[current_room]:
        return 'no item in this room you silly Dwarve!'
    else:
        return room[current_room]['item']


inventory = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while 1:
        print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
        print('           ''You are currently in the', current_room)  # outputs the room the user is currently in
        print('                                      ', 'Inventory:', inventory)
        item = get_item(current_room)
        print('                    ', 'You see', item)
        print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
        if item == 'No item here, only a dragon to fell.':
            print('You were not prepared to face Smaug, you have been desolated.')
            exit()
        direction = input('Enter which direction you would like to head...\n' + '\n' +
                          '                   ''North | East | South | West\n' + '\n' + 'You choose to: ')
        # user inputs the direction they want to go
        if direction == 'Exit':  # if command for exiting the game
            answer = input('Are you sure? ')  # user inputs Yes or No
            if answer == 'Yes':  # if command that will execute and close the game
                exit()
            else:
                direction = input(
                    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n' +
                    '                  ' + 'You are still in the ' + current_room + '\n'  # returns current room

                    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n '
                    'Enter which direction you would like to head...\n' + '\n' +
                    '                   ''North | East | South | West\n' + '\n' + 'You choose to: ')
                # allows user to pick a direction to go in again
        if direction == 'go North' or direction == 'go East' or direction == 'go South' or direction == 'go West':
            new_current_room = get_new_current_room(current_room, direction)
            if new_current_room == current_room:  # if command for entering in a real direction that is not possible
                print(
                    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n' +
                    '             ' +
                    'You cannot go that way. Smaug laughs at your incompetence.')
                # output for not being able to go in the real direction the user typed
            else:
                current_room = new_current_room
        elif direction == 'Take' + item:
            if item in inventory:
                print('Silly Dwarve, you already have this item in your inventory.')
            else:
                for item in inventory:
                    print(item, 'has been added to your inventory.')
                    inventory.append(item)
        else:
            print('                         ' + 'Invalid Direction.')  # output for user keying in a non-real direction
        if len(inventory) == 8:
            print('You have felled Smaug and have lived to tell the tale, now make way to the Prancing Pony for a'
                  'pint of ale and to start your next adventure...The One Ring Awaits...')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop where the item is appended to the inventory, it never makes it into the for loop because the inventory is always empty. The only way to add anything to the inventory is in the for loop. So, try removing the for loop.

```py
elif direction == 'Take ' + item:
            if item in inventory:
                print('Silly Dwarve, you already have this item in your inventory.')
            else:
                inventory.append(item)    
                print(item, 'has been added to your inventory.')
```